# how we create Control Array in VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a form with 4 text box when any textbox get focus then its change back color yellow and other text box back color change to white.

When i work in vb6 its easily done with control array 
For example Create text box control array

set The code like

```
Private Sub text1_GotFocus(Index As Integer)
Call color
Text1(Index).BackColor = vbyellow
End Sub

Private Sub color()
For I = 1 To 4
Text1(I).BackColor = vbWhite
Next I
```

But in VB.net There is no control array so we do some thing like

```
Module Module1
    Public mytext() As TextBox = {Form1.TextBox1, Form1.TextBox2, Form1.TextBox3, Form1.TextBox4}
End Module

    Sub color()
        For i = 0 To 3
            mytext(i).BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
        Next i
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles 
    TextBox1.GotFocus
        color()
        ChangeColor(sender)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.GotFocus
        color()
        ChangeColor(sender)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox3_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox3.GotFocus
        color()
        ChangeColor(sender)
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox4_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox4.GotFocus
        color()
        ChangeColor(sender)

    End Sub

    Sub ChangeColor(ByRef box As TextBox)
        box.BackColor= Drawing.Color.Yellow
    End Sub
End Class
```

But its long code can any one tell me a simple way like my vb6 code

Comment: One option:  the `Handles` clause for GotFocus can have multiple items separated by a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain the Handles clauses together. MSDN example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/handles-clause#example-2

In your case it would look like the following:

```
Private Sub TextBoxChangeColor_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.GotFocus, TextBox2.GotFocus, TextBox3.GotFocus, TextBox4.GotFocus
   Dim this As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
   this.BackColor = Color.Yellow
End Sub

Private Sub TextBoxChangeColor_LostFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.LostFocus, TextBox2.LostFocus, TextBox3.LostFocus, TextBox4.LostFocus
   Dim this As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
   this.BackColor = Color.White
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

You could centralize all your textboxes `GotFocus` events on the same method:

```
' In the New() Sub of your Form:
For Each t As TextBox In {TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4}
    AddHandler t.GotFocus, AddressOf TextBoxList_GotFocus
Next
```

The `TextBoxList_GotFocus` signature:

```
Private Sub TextBoxList_GotFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    color()
    ChangeColor(sender)
End Sub
```

Close enough to your previous handling?

Comment: The `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events are low-level focus events...Instead the `Enter` and `Leave` events should be used for all controls except the `Form` class, which uses the `Activated` and `Deactivate` events. From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus?view=netcore-3.1